# Partitioning a log with minimum cost

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I am struggling with a problem that requires me to find a general pattern and come up with a solving algorithm. The problem goes on like this:
You are given a wood log of length L and a number n that represents the number of pieces the log is to be divided into. You are also given n numbers which display  the desired lengths for each division respectively. The log can be divided only in two pieces at a time and the cost of division is equal to the length of the log you are currently dividing. The problem requires you to find the minimum amount of money needed to divide this log int n pieces of the specified lengths;

Comment: For example, if L=10, n=5 and partitions are {1,3,2,1,3}. The result should be 22.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.